# Microsoft SQL Server, FreeTDS, and formatting of legacy datetime type

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, format, freetds

Why does a value of `datetime` type get displayed with a format using 12 hour clock and AM/PM, while `datetime2` type is returned in ISO format?  This using FreeTDS and the client programs `sqsh` and Perl's `DBD::Sybase`.  How can I change the default date format used for `datetime` so that it matches `datetime2`?

After investigating and finding the answer, a better phrasing of the question would be "How can I change the format string used by FreeTDS for values of `datetime` type returned from the server, and how can I make sure newer types like `datetime2` are encoded properly in the TDS protocol?"  But of course, once you have expressed the question precisely you have already got most of the way to the answer.

Comment: It's ok to ask your own question, but you need to actually make it a *good* question. [Pretend you’re on Jeopardy!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: As for the question, formatting is up to the presentation layer, not the SQL layer. All the date and time data types are just binary values; so it's up to the presentation layer to choose how it *displays* that value to the end user.

Comment: @Larnu you are right in principle, but datetime2 and others come back as string values, not binary data, and then the client library I'm using returns them as-is to the application code.  My question is specifically about FreeTDS, not SQL in general -- although I didn't understand that point until I had found the answer.

Comment: *"but datetime2 and others come back as string values, not binary data"* Not from SQL Server they don't. Maybe FreeTDS converts them (implicitly) to a string based value, but that's not SQL Server's fault.

Comment: I was using the TDSDUMP environment variable to dump out the raw data coming over the wire.  It shows clearly that datetime2 comes back as a string.  I will edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Also your question seems to now just be *"How can I change the format string used by FreeTDS for values of `datetime` type returned from the server?"*. The rest of the question is noise.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that ended up being the question.  But that's also the answer.  My starting point was "why does my application code see a different date format depending on datetime versus datetime2, and how can I change that?".  I'm trying to phrase the question so that somebody in the same situation (who hasn't realized that it's a FreeTDS config issue) will be able to search for it and find the answer.  Perhaps I have not suceeded in that.

Comment: P.S. the reason why datetime2 was coming back as string, not binary, was because of TDS protocol version being set to 7.1.  See Dan Guzman's comment below, which I have incorporated into my answer.  And the question, it turns out, is again a bit different to what I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Microsoft SQL Server introduce new types `date`, `time`, and `datetime2`.  But to fully support them in the TDS protocol you need to speak TDS version 7.3 or later.  Otherwise, they are returned to the client as strings over the wire, as seen by setting the TDSDUMP environment variable:

```
packet.c:410:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 5a 00 63 01 00-81 01 00 00 00 21 00 e7 |...Z.c.. .....!..|
0010 36 00 09 04 d0 00 34 00-d1 36 00 32 00 30 00 32 |6.....4. .6.2.0.2|
0020 00 32 00 2d 00 30 00 31-00 2d 00 31 00 37 00 20 |.2.-.0.1 .-.1.7. |
0030 00 31 00 30 00 3a 00 33-00 35 00 3a 00 32 00 34 |.1.0.:.3 .5.:.2.4|
0040 00 2e 00 38 00 33 00 36-00 36 00 36 00 36 00 37 |...8.3.6 .6.6.6.7|
0050 00 fd 10 00 c1 00 01 00-00 00                   |........ ..|
```

This shows the datetime string '2022-01-17 10:35:24.8366667' being sent as text.  If you use `datetime` you get a binary format:

```
packet.c:410:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 25 00 d6 01 00-81 01 00 00 00 21 00 6f |...%.... .....!.o|
0010 08 00 d1 08 20 ae 00 00-df c4 ae 00 fd 10 00 c1 |.... ... ........|
0020 00 01 00 00 00         -                        |.....|
```

and something similar is seen for `datetime2` provided `TDSVER` is new enough:

```
packet.c:410:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 2b 00 59 01 00-81 01 00 00 00 00 00 21 |...+.Y.. .......!|
0010 00 2a 07 00 d1 08 2b 35-0f ab 69 7b 43 0b fd 10 |.*....+5 ..i{C...|
0020 00 c1 00 01 00 00 00 00-00 00 00                |........ ...|
```

This explains why `datetime2` is returned in a standard date format: because it's the fallback SQL Server uses when the client is using an older protocol.  In a way it's a good result (I prefer the ISO format) but obtained using the wrong means (it's better to use the more efficient binary protocol).

So the first step is to move to a newer TDS version.  This is easiest done by setting the environment variable `TDSVER` to 7.4 (the current latest supported by FreeTDS).

That will make `datetime2` use binary encoding in the same way `datetime` always has done.  And then the application code will get it back as a string using FreeTDS's date formatting.  This looks like a regression compared to the ISO format string, but there is a second step.

This is configured in `/etc/locales.conf`.  As shipped, it has a default format and then overrides for some non-English locales.  In my personal view, the client library is too low-level a place to do locale-aware date formatting, since application code might want to parse the string into its own datetime type, and a change in locale (like switching the order of day and month) should not change application logic.  Locale-aware formatting should come later, at the user interface layer.  But anyway, I replaced the contents of the file with

```
[default]
        date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%z
```

(The `%z` is a FreeTDS extension to date format strings to give milliseconds.)

This brings FreeTDS's client-side date formatting into line with the server-side formatting that happens when the protocol version is old.  So you could in principle just change this date format and continue with the older TDSVER.  It's better to update TDSVER, though, because the binary encoding is more compact and presumably more efficient for the server to generate.

There is one unhappy side effect, though.  When getting back a value of type `date` it will now be formatted as a datetime:

`2022-01-17 00:00:00.000`

Previously, with the older TDS protocol, the client would just see `2022-01-17`.  I believe that fixing this will require a patch to FreeTDS.

I have also seen out-of-memory errors with Perl's `DBD::Sybase` after moving from TDS protocol 7.1 to 7.4.  I will update this answer with more information when I have it.

Comment: Both `datetime` and `datetime2` can and should be returned in native binary format. However, when the negotiated TDS protocol version is prior to 7.3 when the newer `datetime2` type was introduced, types unsupported by the protocol version must be sent/received as strings. The answer is you should use the [latest TDS version](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html) the server supports to avoid string serialization concerns entirely.

Comment: Good point.  I should have checked TDSVER.  It was stuck on 7.1 which predates datetime2 support.